# Automate the creation of letsencrypt certs

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, keyboard

Currently I do my letsencrypt cert creation manually every 3 month.
I have a webspace and use my server, to create the certs. Then I download the certs and add the manually. Since I can't automate the adding to the webspace, I at least want to have the creation automated and have a bash script for that.

So the batch script should do following:

1. `cd letsecrypt`
2. `./letsencrypt-auto --rsa-key-size 4096 -a manual certonly`
3. simulate the input of domain name (e.g `sub.domain.com` )
4. simulate press enter (two times)
5. wait until the script asks to press "enter" again
6. simulate the press of the enter key

Repeat 2-6 with multiple domains

After that zip the `/etc/letsencrypt/live` folder and send it via mail (but the mail thing can also be left out)

I already searched for the simulate enter press: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script

But I don't know, how to tell the script to wait, or how to loop trough 2-6 multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize there’s a [`certbot renew`](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#renewing-certificates) (or `certbot-auto renew`) command, right? It also seems you’re using an outdated version – the command is no longer called `letsencrypt`. The whole system was designed to be automated from the start.

Basically, you want something like:

```
certbot renew --post-hook "/root/mail-cert.sh"
```

[Here are some examples on how to attach a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359/1025421).

I also find it rather hard to believe you’d have some sort of web space where you can run `certbot` but not install the certificates.

Comment: No I create the certs with my server and then load it into my webspace. Two completely different systems. And yes you're right. I can't run certbot on my webspace, that's why I have to use my server for that. Certbot tries to install the certs directly on the server, right? I don't use them on the server, I only want to create them there, download them and load them into my (plesk) webspace.

Comment: No, without a plugin it doesn’t really do anything but place the renewed certificate in the `live` directory. It’s all up to the post-upgrade scripts to do the heavy lifting. Perhaps you can even create one that installs them on your webspace.